# You must use multi-factor authentication to proceed. Please ensure MFA is enforced for your account, and then sign in again using MFA

Tags: azure, entra-id

In Azure , new requirement since Nov 9, 2020 is that all new Application Registrations must have MPNID Configured.

I keep getting this error. No documentation on what to fix.

You must use multi-factor authentication to proceed. Please ensure MFA is enforced for your account, and then sign in again using MFA.
[VjpDekCBS9tULdQpOdAQQe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it after multiple trial and errors.

Double check if your MPN associated Azure AD and current AD are same. You cannot associate MPN with different AD other than one approved.